# Tensorflow (Keras) & Multiprocessing results in lack of GPU memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-multiprocessing

I have a custom DataGenerator that uses Python's Multiprocessing module to generate the training data that is fed to the Tensorflow model.

The problem is whenever a new DataGenerator Process is initialized, it seems that it tries to initialize Tensorflow (which is imported on the top of the code) and allocate some GPU memory for itself.

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory) to limit each process' access to GPU memory and my code worked but I can only use a third of the GPU memory available.

The new Processes & the Tensorflow code are initiated in the same Python file. Is there a proper way to make use of Multiprocessing while forbidding the spawned processes to import Tensorflow and allocate some GPU memory for themselves?

Here's a part of the code (Runs In Windows) for clarification:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from keras.models import load_model

def TrainQueueProcess(queue):
    # This Function Fills The Queue For Other Consumers

def get_model(model_path=None):
    import tensorflow as tf
    import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as ktf

    def get_session(gpu_fraction=0.333):
        gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=gpu_fraction, allow_growth=True)
        return tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))

    ktf.set_session(get_session())

    from keras import Input, Model
    from keras.applications.mobilenetv2 import MobileNetV2
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
    from keras.optimizers import adam
    from keras.utils import plot_model

    input_tensor = Input(shape=(128, 128, 3))
    base_model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor, input_shape=(128, 128, 3), pooling='avg')
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = True

    op = Dense(128, activation='relu')(base_model.output)
    op = Dropout(.25)(op)
    output_tensor = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(op)
    model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=output_tensor)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam(lr=0.0008), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TRAIN_QUEUE = Queue(maxsize=10)
    TRAIN_PROCESS = Process(target=TrainQueueProcess, args=(TRAIN_QUEUE))
    TRAIN_PROCESS.start()

    model = get_model(model_path)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on windows move all your `tf` and `keras` imports into the methods.

[How to avoid loading a parent module in a forked process with Pythons multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641543/how-to-avoid-loading-a-parent-module-in-a-forked-process-with-pythons-multiproce)

Since Windows lacks os.fork() all the imports are imported again in the new process (which in your case include importing tf).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows

Comment: I also get this on Linux (Tensorflow Docker, actually). In particular i get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710977/importing-tensorflow-2-0-gpu-from-different-processes)