# Importing Tensorflow 2.0 gpu from different Processes

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, python-multiprocessing, tensorflow2.0

I'm working on a project in which I got a python module that implements an iterative process and some computations are performed by GPU using tensorflow 2.0. The module works right when used stand-alone from a single process.

Since I have to perform several runs with different parameters I'd like to parallelize the calls, but when I call the module (which imports tensorflow) from a different process, I got `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` and an infinite loop of `CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED`, so the spawned processes hang forever.

Of course I tried [limiting the GPU memory](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth) and it works correctly if I run two different python scripts from different interpreters, but seems to not work in my case.

In particular, if i use

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
    try:
       # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
        for gpu in gpus:
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
            logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
            print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
        print(e)
```

I get the infinite loop of `CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED`, while if i use:

```
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if len(physical_devices) > 0:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
else:
    print("No GPU found, model running on CPU")
```

The process hangs as well but I get an error for each spawned process.

By reading the tensorflow console output, the first spawned process seems to allocate memory on the GPU, however it hangs as well as the other processes that complain about memory being exhausted. The curious thing is that in nvidia-smi GPU Memory doesn't seem exhausted at all.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.48                 Driver Version: 410.48                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN V             Off  | 00000000:03:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 29%   42C    P8    28W / 250W |    755MiB / 12035MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I managed to write a minimal reproducible example of the issue:

File "tf_module.py"

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
    try:
       # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
        for gpu in gpus:
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
            logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
            print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
        print(e)
else:
    print("Running on CPU")

def run(x, y):
    return tf.add(x, y).numpy()
```

File "run.py"

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import tf_module as experiment
def run_exp(params):
    a, b = params
    return experiment.run(a, b)

pool = Pool(2)
params = [(a, b) for a in range(3) for b in range(3)]

results = pool.map(run_exp, params)
```

Moving the TF computation out of the module is not feasible since it is part of a complex pipeline in which also numpy is involved, for this reason I need to parallelize this piece of code.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance