# Understand python multiprocessing child process memory usage with 'spawn' start method

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, ubuntu-18.04, spawn

I am trying to create a child process in python 3.8.0 using multiprocessing module without inheriting the parent's memory. I am using spawn start method `mp.set_start_method('spawn')` for this. But the memory usage of the child process is almost same as the parent process. Code snippets below

I am using code shared here for testing [How can I restrict the scope of a multiprocessing process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477470/how-can-i-restrict-the-scope-of-a-multiprocessing-process)

memtest.py

```
import multiprocessing  as mp
import numpy as np

def foo(x):
    import time
    time.sleep(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')

    dont_inherit = np.ones((500, 100))
    for x in range(3):
        mp.Process(target=foo, args=(x,)).start()
```

run using `python3 memtest.py`

memory usage from top

```
 449m  28m  14m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.44 python3 memtest.py
 34904  10m 5816 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 /srv/env/bin/python3 -c from multiprocessing.resource_tracker import main;main(5)
 252m  26m  13m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.26 /srv/env/bin/python3 -c from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(tracker_fd=6, pipe_handle=20) --multiprocessing-fork
 252m  27m  13m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.21 /srv/env/bin/python3 -c from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(tracker_fd=6, pipe_handle=22) --multiprocessing-fork
 252m  26m  13m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.23 /srv/env/bin/python3 -c from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(tracker_fd=6, pipe_handle=24) --multiprocessing-fork
```

I am using virtualenv with python3.8.0 on ubuntu18.04

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.0
```

What is wrong in this approach of creating a child process? I need to create a lot of child processes that need to be light weight, I initially figured using mp's spawn approach would do this but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rmrmg's answer is misleading.

Spawn will copy over global variables, yes, but it won't copy over memory that's protected by the `__name__=='__main__'` scope. Spawn essentially imports your current module, and when it does this import, the `__name__=='__main__'` block does not activate. This is the point of `__name__=='__main__'` (to protect execution code so that it is not run at import).

Now, in regards to why your memory usage is similar across your processes, that's because your `dont_inherit` is made up of 500*100 ints, which amounts to 4*500*100 = 200000 bytes = 200 kilobytes. Your subprocesses indeed don't have your `dont_inherit` object, the memory saved is just so small you can't even detect it from running `top`.

In the future, you should try to access these kinds of objects directly so that you can confirm whether they're present or not. E.g.

```
import multiprocessing  as mp
import numpy as np

def foo(x):
    global dont_inherit
    print(dont_inherit)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')

    dont_inherit = np.ones((500, 100))
    for x in range(3):
        mp.Process(target=foo, args=(x,)).start()
```

If you run this, you'll see that your print statements will throw an error because nothing is there.

You can also make your `dont_inherit` variable larger by a couple orders so you can actually see the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: spawn also copy global variable so you should either:

1. create processes first, and then dont_inherit. I think this is more elegant but probably not always possible; or
2. in each subprocess del dont_inherit. After subprocess is created you have only one copy of dont_inherit in memory (at least on Linux, where copy-on-write works well), so removal in subprocess "reference" to dont_inherit is rather cheap and fast.

Here is some longer story:
I am not sure what exactly ps measure so I think it is better to use total memory usage (e.g. using htop)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
ctx = mp.get_context('spawn') #or fork, both work the same
q = ctx.Queue()

def proc(q):
    while True:
        msg = q.get()
        print("Q", msg)

longlist = [ x for x in range(60_000_000) ]
#additional 2.3GB in RAM
p = ctx.Process(target=proc, args=(q,))
p.start()
#no change in memory usage 
for i in range( len(longlist) ):
    longlist[i] = longlist[i]+1 #memory usage growing 
# when for is ended you have additional 2.3GB in RAM (now ~4.6GB is used)
# because you have original longlist in subprocess 
# and modified longlist in main processs
```

below the same but with del global variable in subprocess

```
import multiprocessing as mp
ctx = mp.get_context('spawn') #or fork, both work the same
q = ctx.Queue()

def proc(q):
    global longlist
    del longlist
    while True:
        msg = q.get()
        print("Q", msg)

longlist = [ x for x in range(60_000_000) ]
#additional 2.3GB in RAM
p = ctx.Process(target=proc, args=(q,))
p.start()
#no change in memory usage 
for i in range( len(longlist) ):
    longlist[i] = longlist[i]+1 #no change in memory usage
# in this point total memory usage is still ~2.3GB
```