# PyODBC connection getting closed by child process ending

Tags: python, python-multithreading, pyodbc

I am creating a python program that essentially reads in records from an IBM i data queue and processeses them for external use. It is using pyodbc for the connection, and for each record read in, I split off a child fork to process the information, so that I can process multiple concurrently (up to a limit to save on resources, for now in testing that is 5 children).

My code is generally as follows:

```
PIDS = []
def main():
    
    global PIDS
    
    #Establish connection to GreenPRI
    try:
        cnx = pyodbc.connect('DSN=REDACTED; UID=%s; PWD=%s;' % (some.username, some.password))
    except pyodbc.Error as err:
        return # TODO: Error Logging
    curs = cnx.cursor()
    
    #Fetch each data entry from data queue - we need the ordinal position and the message data.
    stmt = textwrap.dedent("""
        SELECT message_data
        FROM TABLE(QSYS2.RECEIVE_DATA_QUEUE(
            DATA_QUEUE => 'MYDTAQ',
            DATA_QUEUE_LIBRARY => 'MYLIB',
            REMOVE => 'YES'
        ))
        """)

    #Loop until the data queue is empty
    forked_pid = -1
    while True:
        
        # Check to see if any child processes have finished - we should reap them
        for pid in PIDS:
            ret_pid, exit_code = os.waitpid(pid, os.WNOHANG)
            
        # Get next statement
        curs.execute(stmt)
        row = curs.fetchone()
        if not row:
            break
        
        # Are we able to spin up a new child process?
        if len(PIDS) >= 5:
            ret_pid, exit_code = os.waitpid(-1, 0)
            PIDS.remove(ret_pid)
        
        forked_pid = os.fork()
        
        # We are in the parent process - add child to list, loop
        if forked_pid > 0:
            PIDS.append(forked_pid)
            continue
        
        # We are in child process - process row, then leave.
        elif forked_pid == 0:
            processRow(row)
            os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT) #yes, this is messy...
            return
        
        # The result was negative, something went wrong in the child creation process - kill everything
        else:
            for pid in PIDS: # Wait for children to finish so we can reap them
                ret_pid, exit_code = os.waitpid(pid, 0)
            os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGABRT)
            # TODO: Error logging
    
    # Cleanup
    for pid in PIDS: # Wait for children to finish so we can reap them
        ret_pid, exit_code = os.waitpid(pid, 0)
    curs.close()
    cnx.close()
```

The issue is, when a child process ends, the ODBC connection gets closed. The parent process still believes that it is open and tries to use it, but I get the following error:

> ('24000', '[24000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Invalid cursor state (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError

I can obviously open the connection, read the row, and close the connection before spinning the child process, but that causes what I feel is unnecessary overhead, unless there is no better way.

I could also read in every data queue record right away, but that causes some concern with data loss if the program crashes in the middle of processing them all.

There are some good reads on the stack that involve both multithreaded programs and ODBC connections, but none that seem to deal with my issue specifically (they are mostly about the connection NOT being closed).

Is there a way to keep the connection alive in the parent process only, or (as a more messy solution) force the connection to stay open until I explicitly call cnx.close()?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - instead of using os.fork, I'm utilizing multiprocessing [spawn](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#contexts-and-start-methods) start method. This essentially creates a new python process that only uses the scope of the called function. My code now looks like:

```
import pyodbc
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.connection import wait

CHILDREN = []

def main():
    
    global CHILDREN
    
    # Establish connection
    try:
        cnx = pyodbc.connect('DSN=REDACTED; UID=%s; PWD=%s;' % (some.username, some.password))
    except pyodbc.Error as err:
        return # TODO: Error Logging
    curs = cnx.cursor()
    
    # Fetch each data entry from WBQSENDPG data queue - we need the ordinal position and the message data.
    stmt = textwrap.dedent("""
        SELECT message_data
        FROM TABLE(QSYS2.RECEIVE_DATA_QUEUE(
            DATA_QUEUE => 'MYDTAQ',
            DATA_QUEUE_LIBRARY => 'MYLIB',
            REMOVE => 'YES'
        ))
        """)
    
    # Loop until the data queue is empty
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    while True:
        
        # Get rid of any children that are finished
        CHILDREN = [child for child in CHILDREN if child.is_alive()]
            
        # Get next statement
        curs.execute(stmt)
        row = curs.fetchone()
        if not row:
            break
        
        # Are we able to spin up a new child process?
        while len(CHILDREN) >= 5:
            CHILDREN = [child for child in CHILDREN if child.is_alive()]
        
        new_child = mp.Process(target=processRow, args=(row,))
        new_child.start()
        CHILDREN.append(new_child)
    
    # Cleanup
    while len(CHILDREN) > 0:
        CHILDREN = [child for child in CHILDREN if child.is_alive()]
        
    curs.close()
    cnx.close()

def processRow(row):
    # ... some code ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while not [code implemented to handle stopping and interrupts, handled by supervisord]:
        time.sleep(10)
        main()
```

Found this solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25477640/10541410) in regards to restricting the scope of multithreaded processes.

It would certainly be cleaner with wait() calls, but for now this is a working solution. Hope it helps someone in the future.